# Initiate with SwiftUI content view instead of ActionViewController in iOS Action Extention

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

[image]My whole code base is in UIKit. I want to build my action extension module using swiftUI.

As I can add **NSExtensionPrincipalClass** as the initial entry point to the extension UI. How can I set the initial entry point to a swiftUI content view.

```
struct ActionExtensionInitialView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your principal class can look like the following (tested & worked with Xcode 11.2)

```
class ActionViewController: UIHostingController<AnyView> {

    // override designated initialiser
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        let contentView = ActionExtensionInitialView() // << SwiftUI root view
        super.init(rootView: AnyView(contentView))
    }

    @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me, but I didn't get the url of extension. How can I do that with UIHostingController?

Comment: Found a solution to @AiltonVieiraPintoFilho 's problem. It seems `viewDidLoad` is not a part of UIHostingController, and that's where you normally receive the URL from the extension. The solution I found was to use `viewWillAppear` instead.

Comment: This does work on Xcode 14 now.

Comment: I get *"Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclassInitializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass"* at `init(nibName...`

Comment: @Daniel I'm having the same issue. I get the error "Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass" because that init method no longer exists in UIHostingController. Did you find a solution? I'm using XCode 15.3 and iOS17.